# How to create an executable from Java class using automake i.e. autotools?

Tags: autotools

I am working on autotools. I have some c++ files which uses java class. I am able to create executable for my project using autotools, but I am not able to create an executable for the java class I have included in the project. My project executes this java executable as a command.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a jar file out of the java classes and install it into DATADIR.